# How to get text value of a clicked item in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here is the code:

```
<li v-for="u in usersList">
    <strong><a class="username" @click="openChatbox">${ u } </a></strong>
</li>
```

and the handling method:

```
openChatbox: function() {
    target = event.target || event.srcElement;
     this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
     this.recepient = target.innerHTML
},
```

The problem is that this method sets `recepient`like `<strong>noob</strong>` when `u` value is `noob`. How can I get only `noob`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass the user like following in the method:

```
<li v-for="u in usersList">
    <strong><a class="username" @click="openChatbox(u)">${ u } </a></strong>
</li>
```

and use it in method like this:

```
openChatbox: function(user) {
   //use user here
},
```